# How to serialize/deserialize partial JSON object using GSON?

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have very complex JSON with many nested fields coming from backend, example,

```
{
   "a": ...
   "b": ...
   "not-required-1":{
       "not-required-2":[
           ...
       ]
       ..
   },
   "not-required-3":{
       "not-required-4":[
           ...
       ]
       ...
   }
}
```

I am only interested in "a" and "b" and I can map to corresponding types for the values. But object has many fields which I don't need but they should serialize when I make changes in "a" and "b".

If I only create type with "a" and "b", when I serialize my object, all "not-required" fields are gone. The only option is to map every field in not-required to corresponding Java class, but they fall in number of 100s.

**Clarification**,

Backend sends JSON, which is processed in my code and I need to send JSON back to backend.. though I don't need to process all the fields, doesn't mean backend doesn't need them.

I want to convert incoming JSON to POJO and use it through out the app, and serialize it back to JSON using GSON.

C#'s JSON.NET library has support for hybird object serialization using Json.Linq.

c# example.

```
 class DataObject{

      [JsonProperty("a")]
      DataA A {get;set;}

      [JsonProperty("b")]
      DataB B {get;set;}

      [JsonProperty("not-required-a")]
      Json.Linq.JsonElement NotRequiredA {get;set;}

      [JsonProperty("not-required-b")]
      Json.Linq.JsonElement NotRequiredB; {get;set;}

 }
```

In C# this way I don't need to map fields of NotRequiredA and NotRequiredB, but they will serialize correctly when needed.

Comment: Unclear: *But object has many fields which I don't need but they should serialize when I make changes in "a" and "b".* You are contradicting yourself. Do you NOT them, or should they SERIALIZE?! You cant have it both ways.

Comment: @GhostCat JSON comes from somewhere, I have to modify and serialize it back and send it somewhere... Some other application (backend) needs those fields which I don't need, I just need to pass.

Comment: did you try using a `JSONObject` instance ? Because it really does not matter what is there in the JSON and you can always manipulate only selected fields. So, there is really no need to create a "partial JSON" just to be able to manipulate some selected fields.

Comment: @ZeekHuge I need something for GSON

Comment: I dont think you are getting it. GSON is to convert Java objects to JSON, so that you are able to serialize it (which means JSON objects can easily be seriealized). But you already have JSON, which can easily be seriealized without using GSON. Just convert it into string. As simple as that.
Serialization is required mostly when you want to transfer an object from one component to other component of the app.

Comment: @ZeekHuge I need to convert incoming JSON to java class, use it throughout the app, and save java class back to JSON using gson. I can't use JSONObject all the way because it does not have type safety and too much of extra work. I want to map incoming JSON to a POJO.

Comment: Now, that makes it clear what you really want. I am not sure if GSON can do this. I would suggest you should extend `JSONObject` class say `ServerResponse extends JSONObject` and add methods `doThisWithA()` and `doThisWithB()` to get this working, if that fits in your need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [JsonElement](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html). For example:

```
 class DataObject{

        @Expose @Serialize("a")
        DataA A;


        @Expose @Serialize("b")
        DataB B;

        @Expose @Serialize("not-required-a")
        JsonElement NotRequired;

        ...

 }
```

Comment: The OP mentioned he had 100s of fields. And he will need to do this with all those fields ?

Comment: You have to define top level fields but nested fields will be taken care of.

Answer (score 0):

i think its the solution .
make a view Model and make get and setter method.

```
YourClass class = gson.fromJson(jsonText , YourClass .class);   
class.getA();
class.getB();
```

point:for gson you should implement all Features in json text.
for example you have a object called not-required-1 .
make a class not-required-1 and set not-required-2 array at that class .

you viewModel Example.

> ```
> public class ViewModel(){
>    A a;
>    B b;
>    not-required-1 Not-required-1;
> }
> ```

your not-required-1 for example:

> ```
> public class not-required-1(){
>    ArrayList<String> not-required-2 = new ArrayList<String>();
> }
> ```

your not-required-1 for example: